# Why continually refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have this page:

[link](http://dizievents.ch/)

pass:dizi

I tried to make a redirection using this code:

**CODE JQUERY:**

```
var url = "http://dizievents.ch/index.php/event/food-n-liquor-dizinvolta-2/";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

On firefox it seems that everything is ok but Chrome is continually refresh the page give.

What I think is that we enter into a infinite while loop.

I do not realize why this happens ... all the examples we have found are with this code.

Can you tell me please what would be the solution to this problem?
You can test the site to see what happens on Chrome

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried so

```
var url = "http://dizievents.ch/index.php/event/food-n-liquor-dizinvolta-2/";
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same page you are on?

Comment: Does the page you are redirecting to have a redirect to itself?

Comment: yes....and do not understand that receive negative note ... it seems a stupid question?

Comment: If you load a page that redirects to itself it will create an infinite loop...what are you trying to accomplish by redirecting maybe we can help you figure this out.

Comment: You could pass parameter in the url when you redirect and check if it exists if it does don't redirect.

Comment: brso05 can you give me a short example please?

Comment: just posted an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var temp = getParameterByName("dontredirect");
if(temp != "true")
{
    var url = "http://dizievents.ch/index.php/event/food-n-liquor-dizinvolta-2/?dontredirect=true";
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

This will only redirect the first time visited.  But we might be able to provide a better answer if you tell us why you want to redirect in the first place...

`getParametersByName()` taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/4028085)

Answer (score 1):

if, as soon as the page loads, you redirect to it again, it will keep reloading.

That javascript will run each time, and it will constantly redirect.

Comment: and how to make it run only once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the $(location)...

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes